# jQuery fade out element, replace content and fade back in

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, fadein

I have a site where I am trying to use a scroll event to 
1) fade out a textual version of the company name, 
2) replace the content of that element with an image file of the company logo and 
3) fade the logo back in.  Issues I'm facing:

- I'm able to get the fade out to work, but cannot get the replace (.html) function and fadeIn method to work at all
- I notice that the fade out does not take place immediately upon the user scrolling beyond 250px from the top; it lags quite a bit, especially with faster page scrolling.

I've tried both the .animate and .fadeIn/.fadeOut versions for the fading, but still had no luck with the callback function properly replacing the element contents and fading it back into view.

My code is below:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
var data = '<img src="assets/template/images/afl_logo_sm.png" width="135" height="55" alt="AFL">'
console.log('Scroll ', scrollTop);
if (scrollTop >= 250) {
  jQuery('a.navbar-brand').stop().animate({
    opacity: 0.0
  }, 500, function() {
    jQuery('a navbar-brand').html(data).fadeIn('fast');
  });
}
});
```

Thanks for any help you can provide,

Sandman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the class selector in the fadein/html code, you are using the class like a descendant selector

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    var data = '<img src="//placehold.it/135X55" width="135" height="55" alt="AFL">'
    if (scrollTop >= 250) {
        jQuery('a.navbar-brand').stop().animate({
            opacity: 0.0
        }, 500, function () {
            jQuery(this).html(data).animate({
                opacity: 1
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m2ju9nry/)

Also, once the animation is done, I think the further scrolling should not repeat it so

```
var flag = false;
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    var data = '<img src="//placehold.it/135X55" width="135" height="55" alt="AFL">'
    if (scrollTop >= 250) {
        if (!flag) {
            flag = true;
            jQuery('a.navbar-brand').stop().animate({
                opacity: 0.0
            }, 500, function () {
                jQuery(this).html(data).animate({
                    opacity: 1
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m2ju9nry/2/)

As for the lagging, the browser is a single threaded application so when there is a faster scrolling the browser may spend more time on updating the view as per the scroll than in the script executing which handles the fadeIn

Comment: Also, for the given example, `fadeIn` probably doesn't work on `opacity: 0`, the element would have to be hidden

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Doh!  So right you are.  Thanks for pointing out that serious oversight on my part.  I tested it and the logo image file now fades in, as expected.  Unfortunately, it looks like tying these animate functions to a scrolling event may not be the best choice as the behavior of the fade out/fade in is just too erratic and unpredictable.  I'll look for another event to tie it to that is more succinct.  Thanks again!